# EGit Eclipse shows modifications even after git hard reset

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I have copied over a git repository and an eclipse installation from one linux machine to another.  I'm using the EGit plugin for eclipse.

"git status" shows no changes, but eclipse indicates that everything has to be commited.  When trying to commit it returns "no changes" message

the eclipse installation is exactly the same..I have simply copied it over.

I've tried a "hard reset" by command line and through the eclipse plugin.

Comment: egit is total rubbish. i would use another tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i met this problem before, it seems this is a bug of eclipse EGIT plugin, pls ref https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=307560

Maybe you can try to update your eclipse plugin and try it later.

Br,
Tim